# Check the first value according to first date

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables

```
 guid | id   | Status
 -----| -----| ----------
 1    | 123  | 0
 2    | 456  | 3
 3    | 789  | 0
```

The other table is

```
 id   | modified date | Status
------| --------------| ----------
1     | 26-08-2017    | 3
1     | 27-08-2017    | 0
1     | 01-09-2017    | 0
1     | 02-09-2017    | 0
2     | 26-08-2017    | 3
2     | 01-09-2017    | 0
2     | 02-09-2017    | 3
3     | 01-09-2017    | 0
3     | 02-09-2017    | 3
3     | 03-09-2017    | 0
```

Every time the status in the first table changes for each id it also modifies date and status  in second table.Like for id 1 status was changed 4 times.

I want to select those ids by joining both tables whose value of status was 0 in its first modified date.
In this example it should return only id 3 because only id 3 has a status value as 0 on it first modified date 01-09-2017.Ids 1&   2 have value 3 in their first modified date.

Any help

Comment: could you also add expected result?

Comment: id
3

Thats it. Because id 3 is only which have status 0 in its first modified date.

Answer (score 1):

Try using below(Assuming first table as A and second table as B):

```
;with cte as (
Select a.id, b.Status, row_number() over(partition by a.id order by [modified date] asc) row_num 
from A 
inner join B
 on a.id = b.id
)
Select * from cte where 
status = 0 and row_num = 1
```

Comment: Good to see we're thinking alike.

Comment: @Matthew Baker I see you've given more freedom to choose desired columns in your query :)

Comment: Nah, I'm just lazy.

Comment: dont we need group by on id in second table?

Comment: I don't think so, did you try to run this?

Answer (score 0):

Think this will do what your looking for.

```
WITH    cte
      AS (SELECT    id
          ,         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY (id) ORDER BY [modified date]) RN
          ,         Status
          FROM      SecondTable
         )
SELECT  *
FROM    FirstTable
JOIN    cte ON FirstTable.id = cte.id
               AND RN = 1
WHERE   cte.Status = 0
```

Just expand out the * and return what fields you need.

Comment: dont we need group by on id in second table?

Comment: No need for one.  We don't need any aggregate values (i.e. max or sum) rather all the values for the first row.  The row number partitioned by id, effectively groups them together, and then the where RN = 1 later selects the first line only.

Comment: Try executing the sub query inside the cte to see the table it produces, that may give you a better idea of how it hangs together.